# Trouble with .htaccess, website won't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

my htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I try to do anything on the website only the main website works ok. If I want to go to login page I'm getting an error:

```
No input file specified.
```

But if I change the .htaccess file to:

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The subpages work, but then I have trouble with the theme...

```
 --> 404 Page Not Found: Themes/default
```

Anyone have any idea to what should I change the htaccess file that the page would work. I'm using CodeIgniter.

OK, I've changed the .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Added ? before the $ sign and now the page loads ok. But now I have another problem with the theme.

```
ERROR - 2017-09-11 06:43:40 --> 404 Page Not Found: Themes/default
```

Also fix this: Must be the right directory path inside the config file.

Comment: whats your URL?

Comment: https://roglic.pro

Comment: seems working fine

Comment: If index.php file resides in root location of Apache server (i.e. `/var/www/html` on Ubuntu), Put as second line `RewriteBase /`. Just for case. If it is in some subdirectory, set it as `RewriteBase /nameofsubdir/`. Reload and/or restart Apache then check what you have there. Also, as @AbdullaNilam pointed, it could be your browser cache issue: close all browser windows and test it in private window after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA, L]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, but I've allready changed the htaccess file. Now I have trouble with the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error: But I don't think this is now the issue with the .htaccess file. Had also trouble with the base url....I've had http://.... but my website uses ssl certificate so I've changed the https://...and now it works!